# Minimise $\|h-h_i\|+\lambda\|h-u\|$ for $\lambda \in [0,100]$

Tags: optimization

I would be thankful if anyone can answer my question. This is a very basic question. Let's say we wish to minimise the quantity

$$\hat{h}= \|h-h_i\|+\lambda\|h-u\|,$$

where:

$$h=[13,17,20, 17,    20, 14, 17, 18, 16, 15, 15, 12, 19, 13, 17, 13]^\top,\\  h_i=[18,    17,    14,    13,    17,    15,    17,    19,    12,    20,    15,   13,    16,    17,    20,    13]^\top, \\u = [16, 16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16]^\top,\\
\text{with }\lambda \in [0,100].$$

I know this is a very basic question, but please help me to understand. Also, please suggest me any book where I can start from zero to learn to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: No, idea. Please help me to understand this equation.

Comment: There is no _equation_ in your question. An equation is `something = something else' and you never used the '=' sign.

Comment: I have edited the question, is it still not complete? I found the same equation in an article.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht  Please see the question once again.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht $\lambda$ can take any value between 0 and 100.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Thank you so much. Basically, this is my first time posting any question. WIll definitely improve with time.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda = -\frac {\|h-h_i\|}{\|h-u\|}$ seems to make $\|h-h_i\|+\lambda\|h-u\|$ equal zero.

But I'm unsure if that is what you are looking for...

Comment: Can you please solve it numerically for the values given above, if $\lambda =0.5$. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\lambda$ needs to be positive, immediately you see that $\| h-h_i\|$ will be the smallest value you can obtain (because $\| h-u\|$ is positive). Now simply compute that.